# Calculation of illumination from the Sun and sky - explanation needed

Tags: visible-light, scattering

I found a nice text about the illumination of the sky with respect of the position of the Sun

https://www.brikbase.org/sites/default/files/ies_030.pdf

where I could find the following formula:

[image]

What I would like to have explained are:

IO  and M values.

Could it be possible?

Comment: How can that formula be correct unless $E_s =1$? And if $E_s$ is $1$, why write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please transcribe or paraphrase enough of the surrounding text so that this question can be intelligible without reference to a third-party link and add it to your question.

"IO" is just $10$ on the author's typewriter.

$M$ will be the corresponding physical observable to the coefficient $\epsilon$, giving a unitless number when multiplied together. From the context, it's the mass of a meter-square column of atmosphere in the direction of the light, corresponding to $\epsilon$ being the mass absorption coefficient. If $M$ was the moles of air in the column and and $\epsilon$ was the molar absorption coefficient, you'd get the same number, so it doesn't really matter which pair you choose.